# De-Normalization of XML using XSLT 2.0

Tags: html, xslt-2.0, denormalization

I am trying to denormalise XML using XSLT 2.0.

Below is the XML and the expected output of same. It will be great help of someone can provide the XSLT for achieving this.The denormalization should work only for tags starting with "Change" and not other tags. Other tags should remain as it is.

Sample Input XML

```
<p> This is normal text

            <changebold>This is new line</changebold>

            My Name is

            <table>

                        <tr>

                                    <td>FirstName</td>

                                    <td>LastName</td>

                                    <td>Testing for <changebold>Bold <changeitalic>Italic <changeunderline>UnderLine</changeunderline>

                                                            </changeitalic>

                                                </changebold>

                                    </td>

                        </tr>

            </table>

            <changebold>The Test <changeitalic>of Chemistry<changeunderline>is passed</changeunderline>

                        </changeitalic> and for biology <changeunderline>the result</changeunderline> is unknown <changeunderline> and under process.</changeunderline>

                        <changeitalic>The result</changeitalic> of same<changeunderline>will be</changeunderline> displayed on  <changeitalic>noticeboard soon.</changeitalic>

            </changebold>

            <table>table heading <tr>Row <td>Cell1</td>Row End</tr>Table Heading end. </table>

</p>
```

Expected Output from above XML

```
<p> This is normal text

            <changebold>This is new line</changebold>

            My Name is

            <table>

                        <tr>

                                    <td>FirstName</td>

                                    <td>LastName</td>

                                    <td>Testing for <changebold>Bold </changebold>

                                                <changebold>

                                                            <changeitalic>Italic</changeitalic>

                                                </changebold>

                                                <changebold>

                                                            <changeitalic>

                                                                        <changeunderline>UnderLine</changeunderline>

                                                            </changeitalic>

                                                </changebold>

                                    </td>

                        </tr>

            </table>

            <changebold>The Test </changebold>

            <changebold>

                        <changeitalic>of Chemistry</changeitalic>

            </changebold>

            <changebold>

                        <changeitalic>

                                    <changeunderline>is passed</changeunderline>

                        </changeitalic>

            </changebold>

            <changebold> and for biology </changebold>

            <changebold>

                        <changeunderline>the result</changeunderline>

            </changebold>

            <changebold> is unknown </changebold>

            <changebold>

                        <changeunderline> and under process.</changeunderline>

            </changebold>

            <changebold>

                        <changeitalic>The result</changeitalic>

            </changebold>

            <changebold> of same</changebold>

            <changebold>

                        <changeunderline>will be</changeunderline>

            </changebold>

            <changebold> displayed on  </changebold>

            <changebold>

                        <changeitalic>noticeboard soon.</changeitalic>

            </changebold>

            <table>table heading <tr>Row <td>Cell1</td>Row End</tr>Table Heading end. </table>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look this XSLT which is able to produce desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="(node() | @*)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--To check if element starts with change and has some child element with the name of change -->
  <xsl:template
    match="*[starts-with(name(self::*), 'change') and child::*[starts-with(name(self::*), 'change')]]">
    <xsl:call-template name="checkNode">
      <xsl:with-param name="element" select="self::*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This checkNode is producing almost 90% result but it fails when we have <changebold>Bold <changeitalic>Italic <changeunderline>UnderLine</changeunderline>
  it is producing result like:
  <changebold>
    <changeitalic>Italic </changeitalic>
      <changeitalic>
      <changeunderline>UnderLine</changeunderline>
      </changeitalic>
  </changebold>
  -->
  <xsl:template name="checkNode">
    <xsl:param name="element"/>
    <xsl:param name="nesting">
      <xsl:for-each select="$element/node()">
        <xsl:element name="{self::node()/parent::node()/name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:for-each select="$nesting/child::*">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(self::*/child::*) gt 1">
          <xsl:call-template name="getChild">
            <xsl:with-param name="element" select="self::*"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Here, we are iterating again to get the desired result which was not done by previous 'checkNode' template-->
  <xsl:template name="getChild">
    <xsl:param name="element"/>
    <xsl:param name="start" select="xs:integer(1)"/>
    <xsl:param name="countChild" select="count($element/child::*)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$start le $countChild">
        <xsl:element name="{self::*/name()}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="child::*[$start]"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="getChild">
          <xsl:with-param name="element" select="$element"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="countChild" select="$countChild"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```